# Data structure for efficient substring searches in a phone book application

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I want to store contacts on phone book,
and I want that the user will search just part of the name.

for example :
The phone book contains :

```
Tom, John, Eve, Barbi ,Johnathon.
```

Now, the user search for "hn" , the result needs to be "John" and "Johnathon".

I read about TRIE , but its good just for prefixes.

Thanks

Comment: what´s the connection to `java` and `c++` here?

Comment: You should say how mich coding you are willing to invest. Are you looking for a ready made project that you can make use of? Or want to develop sth "on your own"?

Comment: Hi  Matthias,  thanks for your response. I dont looking for a ready made project, I am just intersting what the argorithm to solve problem like this.

Comment: You can concatenate all the strings and use some string data-structure like suffix tree or suffix array on the resulting string, that will probably serve you. I'd choose suffix array because it is easier to implement and manage.

Now, if we join more than one string, how would we distinguish each of them in the resulting string? The answer is, using a special character at the joining part which will not appear in any other string. Like, "hello$world", here $ is that special character.

Answer (score 3):

In a phone book, typically,

1. The number of entries is not that large.
2. Entries are added/deleted/modified, much less frequently than they are searched.

I suggest, therefore, that you maintain a hash table mapping substrings to lists of entries in which they appear. This hash table should be modified when entries are modified.

For example, suppose you add a new entry with length *n*. This entry has at most *n<sup>2</sup>* substrings. For each such substring:

1. If it is not in the hash table, add an entry mapping the substring to an empty list.
2. Irrespective of whether it was in the hash table or not, add this entry to the list corresponding to the substring (just make sure you don't add it twice).

If you have *m* words, and the longest word is *n*, then *O(m n<sup>2</sup>)* should be enough to store everything. For a typical phonebook, this is tiny.

Comment: A *straight-forward yet effective for this scenario* solution.

Answer (score 0):

For most people, their address book is gonna have less than 1000 entries in it. You can definitely get by with just substring search for "hn" in each name, in turn.

Something like, in Python:

```
results = [name for name in address_book if name.contains(search_term)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I develop your project, that's would be my solution; the code below is just pseudocode, you can try this in every programming language

```
result;
booklist;
search_keyword;
if(length(search_keyword) == 1) //people generaly types first char of the name to find him/his in their list.
    for i=0 to n //traverse 0 to n
        if(booklist[i][0] == search_keyword[0]) //check first letter with booklist element and search_keyword
            result.push(booklist[i]);

if(length(search_keyword) == 2) //people generaly types first two letter of the name to find him/his in their list.
    for i=0 to n //traverse 0 to n
        if(booklist[i][0] == search_keyword[0] AND booklist[i][1] == search_keyword[1]) //check first letter with booklist element and search_keyword
            result.push(booklist[i]);

if(length(search_keyword) > 2)
    for i=0 to n //traverse 0 to n
        if(booklist[i].contains(search_keyword))
            result.push(booklist[i]);

return result;
```

In this algorithm, most users will wait for O(n) time complexity.